# tmpfs /run running out of space but it is not really being used

Tags: tmpfs

Good night! I am trying to figure out what is happening with my /run directory!

If I look at /run size using df -h | grep tmpfs it returns something like:

```
tmpfs                        10G   10G     0 **100%** /run
tmpfs                        32G   12K   32G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                       5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                        32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                       6,3G     0  6,3G   0% /run/user/1001
tmpfs                       6,3G     0  6,3G   0% /run/user/0
```

So I decided to look inside it and try to discover what is happening...

```
cd /run 
sudo du -hs .
**667M**    .
```

Only **667 MB** of du command versus **10G of df**, Can't understand why. because there is **no** hidden file on the folder.

Searching for hidden files:

```
cd /var/run; ls -a
.              crond.pid     lock              network         postgresql2             rpcbind.lock     sshd        utmp
..             crond.reboot  log               NetworkManager  proftpd                 rpcbind.sock     sshd.pid    xtables.lock
agetty.reload  dbus          motd.dynamic      openvpn         proftpd.delay           rpc_pipefs       sysconfig   zabbix
apache2        exim4         motd.dynamic.new  pacct_shadow.d  proftpd.pid             rsyslogd.pid     systemd
atd.pid        initctl       mount             pcscd           proftpd.scoreboard      samba            tmpfiles.d
atop.pid       initramfs     mysqld            php             proftpd.scoreboard.lck  sendsigs.omit.d  udev
console-setup  jenkins       netdata           postgresql      rpcbind                 shm              user
```

Someone knows what is this?

```
cd /run 
du -hs *
0   agetty.reload
4,0K    apache2
4,0K    atd.pid
4,0K    atop.pid
0   console-setup
4,0K    crond.pid
0   crond.reboot
0   dbus
4,0K    exim4
0   initctl
4,0K    initramfs
0   jenkins
0   lock
664M    log
4,0K    motd.dynamic
0   motd.dynamic.new
0   mount
4,0K    mysqld
4,0K    netdata
12K network
0   NetworkManager
8,0K    openvpn
316K    pacct_shadow.d
0   pcscd
4,0K    php
824K    postgresql
0   postgresql2
0   proftpd
16K proftpd.delay
4,0K    proftpd.pid
4,0K    proftpd.scoreboard
0   proftpd.scoreboard.lck
0   rpcbind
0   rpcbind.lock
0   rpcbind.sock
0   rpc_pipefs
4,0K    rsyslogd.pid
0   samba
0   sendsigs.omit.d
0   shm
0   sshd
4,0K    sshd.pid
4,0K    sysconfig
144K    systemd
4,0K    tmpfiles.d
1,8M    udev
0   user
8,0K    utmp
0   xtables.lock
0   zabbix
```

Running Debian GNU/Linux version 9X

**UPDATE 1:** Adding more information as asked on the comments (by xhienne) :

```
# lsof /run
COMMAND     PID         USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
systemd       1         root   19r   REG   0,19     4224      46178 /run/utmp
systemd       1         root   61u  FIFO   0,19      0t0      55478 /run/systemd/initctl/fifo
rpcbind    1033         root    4rW  REG   0,19        0      57955 /run/rpcbind.lock
atd        1079       daemon    3uW  REG   0,19        5      57973 /run/atd.pid
ModemMana  1085         root   10w  FIFO   0,19      0t0      45138 /run/systemd/inhibit/1.ref
NetworkMa  1088         root   16w  FIFO   0,19      0t0      14466 /run/systemd/inhibit/2.ref
systemd-l  1098         root   16r  FIFO   0,19      0t0      45138 /run/systemd/inhibit/1.ref
systemd-l  1098         root   17r  FIFO   0,19      0t0      14466 /run/systemd/inhibit/2.ref
systemd-l  1098         root   18r  FIFO   0,19      0t0 2553842116 /run/systemd/sessions/720821.ref
proftpd    6585      proftpd    7u   REG   0,19      656 2553667203 /run/proftpd.scoreboard
proftpd    6585      proftpd    8u   REG   0,19        0 2553667204 /run/proftpd.scoreboard.lck
atop       7070         root    3rr  REG   0,19   319488  488699385 /run/pacct_shadow.d/0000000054.paf
sudo      15609         root  cwd    DIR   0,19       60      55523 /run/log/journal
su        15610         root  cwd    DIR   0,19       60      55523 /run/log/journal
su        15610         root    6w  FIFO   0,19      0t0 2553842116 /run/systemd/sessions/720821.ref
bash      15620         root  cwd    DIR   0,19     1040      14338 /run
cron      17987         root    3uW  REG   0,19        6      58020 /run/crond.pid
zabbix_ag 21946       zabbix    3wW  REG   0,19        0 2493467300 /run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid
zabbix_ag 21947       zabbix    3w   REG   0,19        0 2493467300 /run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid
zabbix_ag 21949       zabbix    3w   REG   0,19        0 2493467300 /run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid
zabbix_ag 21950       zabbix    3w   REG   0,19        0 2493467300 /run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid
zabbix_ag 21951       zabbix    3w   REG   0,19        0 2493467300 /run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid
zabbix_ag 21952       zabbix    3w   REG   0,19        0 2493467300 /run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid
proftpd   25070 proftpd    7u   REG   0,19      656 2553667203 /run/proftpd.scoreboard
proftpd   25070 proftpd    8u   REG   0,19        0 2553667204 /run/proftpd.scoreboard.lck
proftpd   25070 proftpd   10u   REG   0,19    12608   87916632 /run/proftpd.delay
proftpd   25070 proftpd   11u   REG   0,19      656 2553667203 /run/proftpd.scoreboard
lsof      25460         root  cwd    DIR   0,19     1040      14338 /run
lsof      25461         root  cwd    DIR   0,19     1040      14338 /run
openvpn   25976         root    4w   REG   0,19      331      40022 /run/openvpn/rack.status
bash      47222      hidden  cwd    DIR   0,19       60      55523 /run/log/journal
systemd-j 48288         root  mem    REG   0,19  8388608 2507964540 /run/log/journal/b87e2474d47d4de99c361012bdece10f/system.journal
systemd-j 48288         root  mem    REG   0,19        8      55519 /run/systemd/journal/kernel-seqnum
systemd-j 48288         root   29u   REG   0,19  8388608 2507964540 /run/log/journal/b87e2474d47d4de99c361012bdece10f/system.journal
```

Comment: You didn't search for (opened) deleted files: use `lsof /run`.

Comment: @xhienne Posted the output of it on the question still not clear for me....

Comment: Thanks. The output of `lsof` doesn't show any deleted file. My guess is that you are running out of memory, since `/run` is a ramdisk. It would be interesting to have the output of `free`.

Comment: 20537564 kB MemAvailable: 55883464 kB I was able to workaround it by increasing the size of the tmpfs by doing a remount, so there is ram memory available, but this problem is still repeating if I wait for a couple of months... I fear that in some point I will need to restart the server.

Comment: @xhienne When I used lsof | grep /run instead of lsof /run it returned some deleted files, but they look like to be zero sized, but I will try to stop the service keeping the lock .

Comment: @xhienne no effect :-( the files are too small... no more files on the list...

Comment: I think this question has been answered here: https://superuser.com/questions/1100059/tmpfs-deleting-files-wont-free-the-space

Comment: @Shōgun8 But that is exactly what we tryed yesterday....without success?

Comment: Did you do that in the mounted partition? I.e., ```lsof -nP +L1 /tmp```

Comment: Many of these files are either deleted or use the same 'node' numbers.

Comment: @Shõgun8 with this command I am seeing some relevant stuff, but not in /run ., I am runing it like: "lsof -nP +L1 /run" but getting something like: apache2   17468 www-data   47w   REG    8,2 2233777188     0   18750749 /var/log/apache2/access.log.1 (deleted) How this can be related to /run? :-(   Tryed to restart systemd, apache a lot of other services not changing the space being used on /run. I think I am facing a BUG and something tells me it is related to systemd.

Comment: I think I have a clue, when I runned  journalctl --vacuum-size=1M, the used space in /run immediately increased instead of reducing... Don't know if it is coincidence...